# admin page login and access in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want something that when admin users login it redirects to admin page and when normal users login it redirects to dashboard

and normal users shouldn't access admin page

- i dont want 2 login page!!, i need 1 login page

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on the login function.

```
if(check if user is admin){
  return redirect('/admin');
}else{
  return redirect('/');
}
```

As for security, take a look at the laravel `Middlewares`

If you can show us some code, we might help you with more on point information.

Answer (score 0):

use roles, and assign roles to user every time you add a new user. so whenever a user logins, check his role, if its admin, redirect to admin panel, and if its user, redirect to user panel.

Make sure to use a proper middleware also..

Answer (score 0):

Just check the role of user in Controller when login and redirect to Admin/User page based on that

```
if($loguser->admin == 1){
    return redirect('admin/dashboard');
}else {
    return redirect('home/dashboard');
}
```

To redirect normal users when accessing admin page you can use middleware
Example code :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->admin == 1) {
            return $next($request);
     }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write custom method into `LoginController` with checking user's role after success auth: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: where's LoginController

Comment: Check documentation from my link. If don't get it - start from scratch

Answer (score 0):

You can add a user type field in your user table. then at the login time, you can check user type. suppose user type 1 is the admin then.

```
if($loguser->type == 1){
   return redirect('admin/dashboard');
}
if($loguser->type == 2) {
   return redirect('user/dashboard');
}
```

Comment: where write these lines?

Comment: in your controller where you are checking user is available or not

Comment: public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['mail'], 'password' => $request[password]])) {
           //your checking will be here
        }
    }